# How to declare Application object

Tags: python, pyqt

By now I've been using this syntax while declaring an `Application` object:

```
if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Just read it there is another "recommended" way of doing the same.

```
if ( __name__ == '__main__' ):
    app = None
    if ( not QtGui.QApplication.instance() ):
        app = QtGui.QApplication([])
```

There was no explanation why it is "recommended". Any ideas why?

Comment: BTW: you don't need `()` in `if` - it is not `C/C++`.

Comment: Recommended or not, this syntax would make sure you only create a new instance if none has been created already. Your application should not have more than one qapplication instance. Why in this case you wouldn't pass the argv list is beyond me.

Comment: What is the reason we send `sys.argv` to `QApplication()` as an argument?

Comment: How much of the difference between `app = QtGui.QApplication([])` and           `app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)`?

Comment: We send `sys.argv` if we want to run program with arguments - for example "image filename" to show it (if it is image viewer).